# Regarding XPath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

When i am checking an XPath of a link, it appears to be:

```
id('content')/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[1]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[4]/x:a[2]
```

How can I use it in in target?

If I copy it directly, it doesn't give a result. What else can be done in this regard?

Comment: be more clear. what's the context. what link? what 'target'?

Comment: Suppose i want to pick a field in Xpath, in selenium IDE's 'target' tab how can i use that xpath? Or simply how xpath can be used in Selenium IDE? where we shall place that xpath code?

Comment: Yikes, the web page has tables nested 8 deep??!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Selenium, if the locator starts with `//` then it is assumed that the locator is an XPath, in your case the you will need to precede your locator with `xpath=` to make it explicit.

That said, your XPath looks very fragile. You might find that one of the other supported locator types would be more suitable, or a simplified XPath.

- Locating elements with Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#locating-elements
- Locating tips/techniques: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.html

Comment: Instead of Xpath if i want to check for Css, how can i do so?

Comment: Here's a good resource for CSS selectors in Selenium: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/ I wouldn't be able to provide a working example without more information on your HTML source.

Comment: have worked a lot with that, used firebug to cater that problem and to generate a more simplified XPATH, and now amazingly its working. Thanks a lot for your help Dave :)